# The correct way to use MapView (inside an Android Service)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What I want to achieve: get location's snapshot inside a backgound Service or AsyncTask, so I can then show them to the User in a screen like this one:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtUFn.png)

1. I am inside an Android Service
2. I want to create a map, add a marker and then take a snapshot of it (I'll save it on the apps database)
3. Here is how I am creating the map:

My Service:

```
public class GetCurrentLocationService extends Service implements OnMapReadyCallback 
(...)   


@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Util.log(TAG, "Service started");

        locationService = new LocationService(GetCurrentLocationService.this);
        mapService = new MapService(GetCurrentLocationService.this);
        mapService.setLiteMode(true);
        mapService.setAddMarker(true);

        mapService.connect();

        GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions().liteMode(true);
        mapView = new MapView(GetCurrentLocationService.this, options);
        mapView.onCreate(null);
        mapView.setLayoutParams(new MapView.LayoutParams(300, 400));
        Util.log(TAG, mapView.getHeight() + " " + mapView.getWidth());
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

4. Still inside the Service, when the map is ready...

   @Override
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
       Util.log(TAG, "Map ready: " + googleMap);

   ```
   googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
   mapService.setMap(googleMap);

   try {
       location = mapService.getLastKnowLocation();

       if (location != null) {
           Util.log(TAG, "Got location: " + location.toString());
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   Util.log(TAG, "Get current location service done");

   stopSelf();
   ```

   }
5. mapService.getLastKnowLocation() will take the snapshot like this:

   public void takeSnapshot(boolean _saveIfPersisted) {
           this.saveIfPersisted = _saveIfPersisted;

   ```
   if(map != null) {
       Util.log(TAG, "Map ready: " + map);

       if(!liteMode) {
           map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
               public void onMapLoaded() {
                   snapshot();
               }
           });
       } else {
           snapshot();
       }
   }
   ```

   }

   private void snapshot() {
       map.snapshot(new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
           public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap bitmap) {
               Util.log(TAG, "Snapshot is ready");

   ```
           if (location != null) {
               Util.log(TAG, "Location is ready");

               // Resize the snapshot to thumbnail size
               Bitmap resizedBitmap = scaleCenterCrop(bitmap, MAP_SNAPSHOT_WIDTH, MAP_SNAPSHOT_HEIGHT);
               //bitmap.recycle();

               // Set snapshot to the location and save it (if asked for)
               location.setSnapshot(resizedBitmap);

               LocationService locationService = new LocationService(context);
               if (saveIfPersisted && locationService.isPersisted(location)) {
                   Util.log(TAG, "Location is persisted");

                   locationService.save(location);
               }
           }
       }
   });
   ```

   }
6. Heres LogCat:

   09-01 22:27:42.017 16520-16520/br.org.knob.followme D/GetCurrentLocationSvc: Service started
   09-01 22:27:42.022 16520-16520/br.org.knob.followme I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 11509438
   09-01 22:27:42.122 16520-16520/br.org.knob.followme D/GetCurrentLocationSvc: 0 0
   09-01 22:27:42.123 16520-16520/br.org.knob.followme D/GetCurrentLocationSvc: Map ready: com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap@2c0fed8
   09-01 22:27:42.132 16520-16520/br.org.knob.followme D/MapFragment: Last know location: Location[fused -30,051789,-51,197934 acc=22 et=+8d5h25m32s546ms]
   09-01 22:27:42.183 3658-3668/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 212329(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 13(448KB) LOS objects, 40% free, 19MB/32MB, paused 1.325ms total 162.150ms
   09-01 22:27:42.204 16520-16520/br.org.knob.followme D/MapFragment: Marker added
   09-01 22:27:42.204 16520-16520/br.org.knob.followme D/MapFragment: Got location, now try to get snapshot
   09-01 22:27:42.205 16520-16520/br.org.knob.followme D/MapSnapshotService: Map ready: com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap@2c0fed8
   09-01 22:27:42.206 16520-16520/br.org.knob.followme D/GetCurrentLocationSvc: Got location: Location{id=null, latitude='-30.0517891', longitude='-51.1979342'}
   09-01 22:27:42.206 16520-16520/br.org.knob.followme D/GetCurrentLocationSvc: Get current location service done
   09-01 22:27:42.207 16520-16520/br.org.knob.followme D/GetCurrentLocationSvc: Service destroyed
   09-01 22:27:42.224 16520-17511/br.org.knob.followme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: androidmapsapi-Snapshot
                                                                         Process: br.org.knob.followme, PID: 16520
                                                                         **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0**
                                                                             at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:903)
                                                                             at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:882)
                                                                             at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:849)
                                                                             at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.eb.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509438:4)
                                                                             at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bf.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509438:4)

Comment: Hey @F. F. Knob! I don't know if your business logics requires a snapshot of the map. But wouldn't it be better if you stored on you database the location you are receiving on your app?

Comment: Hello Davi, thanks for your answer... Let me clarify what I am trying to achieve:

Comment: Hello Davi, thanks for your answer... Let me clarify what I am trying to achieve:

1) The app's service will keep getting the user's location througout the day
2) I do save this location in the app's database
3) Besides the geo location, I also would like to save a small snapshot of the location, because...
4) The user has access to a History Activity, basically a log of the locations he passed by... Each location saved should show the location's snapshot

Comment: That's why I'd like to take this snapshot in the sevice, since I am already getting the location...

Anyway, I am kind of convinced that is not possible to take this snapshot inside a Service or a AsyncTask, since there is no MapView available...

Comment: Oh, ok...  I think an alternative to that would be a list containing the user's location on each row using the lite mode of google maps alongside a RecyclerView (Wich you already is using when trying to take the snapshot). Perhaps this should solve your issue?